# MVC Routing How to avoid the URL getting changed with parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to avoid the URL getting changed with parameters.

I have Account/Microland, where Microland is parameter, whenever i pass Account/Microland, the url is automatically set to Account/Logon even after specifying the routing values as below

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "defaultAccountlogin",
                url: "Account/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Logon" }
                );
```

Comment: is this the only route or are there others as well

Answer (score 0):

Parmaters != action

You need to pass Account/ActionYouRequire/Microland.

Comment: i am passing Account/Logon/Microland, however it is getting changed to Account/Logon/Logon

Comment: Huh? Is Microland a parameter or controller? And do you have a controller and a parameter called Logon???